# c# console.clear wpf result of cmd command in variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have function that get me a whole cmd

```
public void GetMovieData(string FileName)

    {

        string command = "mediainfo --Inform=file://custom.txt " + FileName;
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        using (Process p = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            p.StandardInput.Flush();

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
            p.StandardInput.Flush();                
            p.StandardInput.Close();
            t_Dane_tech.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();



        }

    }
```

now i want only get these lines that are below command. Now when i hit the button i get info: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation bla bla bla and result of my command. I just want that command result... It can be done?

Comment: Run mediainfo.exe instead of cmd.exe

Comment: i use mediainfo cli that can be use only through cmd

Comment: If i run mediainfo.exe it says it can be only run with params. When i add params after exe it crash...

Answer (score 0):

```
  string command = "mediainfo --Inform=file://custom.txt " + FileName + " > "plik.txt";
```

And now streamreader and at the end of the function delete file. I think i overthink it but it is just fine :D